# @PostConstruct executed twice in class with @Singleton and @Startup on JBoss 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, cdi

I have a following class:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerConfig;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.mysite.Config;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class Scheduler {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Inject @Config
    private Logger log;

    @Inject @Config
    private Integer delay;

    @Inject @Config
    private Integer interval;

    @Inject @Config
    private Boolean enabled;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initTimer() {
        if (enabled) {
            TimerConfig tc = new TimerConfig();
            tc.setPersistent(false);
            timerService.createIntervalTimer(delay, interval, tc);
        }
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout(Timer timer) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

package structure:

- java

  - dataloaders (here are the problematic classes)
  - other packages
- resources

  - META-INF, config, etc

While deploying to JBoss 7.1.1 the initTimer method of this class is always called twice, which then results in the timeout being called twice every time.

I already know from [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/635738) and [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-2785) that it's a bug in JBoss (which supposedly is fixed for 7.1.1 but apparently it isn't). My question then is - does anybody know of any workaround that I could use to stop doubled execution of the @PostConstruct methods (I have more classes like that, all of them have the same problem)?

I've seen more questions like this, but they're all connected either with some REST library or Spring and CDI initializing the bean two times - it's not the case here.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please add your import statements, as well as your packaging structure.

Comment: Added, if you need any more info, let me know.

Comment: Is your EJB jar inside a WAR ?

Comment: It is a one pom project with war packaging. There is no jar for EJBs, everything is under WEB-INF/classes. Could this be a problem? It's a project that we inherited from a different company, I didn't even think about packaging yet.

Comment: I once had a similar problem caused by a duplicate beans.xml, one in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF, another one in src/main/resources/META-INF. Might be worth checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a problem with app packaging, the second app was underneath and its' xml config was picked up again causing objects to be constructed twice. My bad, thanks to @hwellmann for the hint.